# NameError: Variable not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Please, below is my code to plot a dataframe. 
[The DataFrame to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBlBK.png)

On the image above is the picture of the dataframe to plot.

Below is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 10)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 10)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 15)

targets = ['Mkt-RF', 'SMB', 'HML', 'RMW', 'CMA', 'RF']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'purple', 'black', 'yellow']

for index2, color in zip(targets, colors):
    ax.scatter(finalDF.loc[finalDF.Target == index2, 'Principal_Component_1'], finalDf.loc[finalDF.Target == index2, 'Principal_Component_2'], c = color, s=50)
ax.legend(indexes)
ax.grid()
```

The error message display is:

```
<ipython-input-19-5ee92622d5a5> in <module>
      9 
     10 for index2, color in zip(targets, colors):
---> 11     ax.scatter(finalDF.loc[finalDF.Target == index2, 'Principal_Component_1'], finalDf.loc[finalDF.Target == index2, 'Principal_Component_2'], c = color)
     12 ax.legend(indexes)
     13 ax.grid()

NameError: name 'finalDf' is not defined
```

Team, please assist. I have being look at this for the whole day.

Comment: There is no variable or other object with the name `finalDf` in this code. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: where in your code have you defined `finalDF` you dont show it in the extract you have given

Comment: Also while *none* of `finalDf` and `finalDF` exist in the code you've shown, presumably one of them is defined elsewhere and the other one is a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in the given code have you defined a variable named `finalDF`. That's what the error message is saying.

Comment: I have a variable named finalDF. This is the dataframe I want to plot.     Below is the code. principalDF = pd.DataFrame(data=component_data, columns = ['Principal_Component_1', 'Principal_Component_2'])
finalDF = pd.concat([principalDF, transposedFactor[['index']]], axis=1)
finalDF = finalDF.rename({'index':'Target'}, axis =1)
finalDF

Comment: Python is case sensitive. finalDF and finalDf are different variables.

Comment: Thanks Bill Lynch. Thats the solution to my problem.